# iterator a set in array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, unordered-set

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;
void arraySet(unordered_set<int> n[]){
    for(auto it1 = n->begin(); it1!= n->end(); it1++){
        cout << "n[" <<*it1<<"]: ";
        // for(auto it = it1->begin(); it!= it1->end(); it++){
        //     cout << *it <<" ";
        // }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    unordered_set<int> n[3];
    n[0].insert(734);
    n[0].insert(23);
    n[0].insert(634);
    n[1].insert(2);
    n[1].insert(1);
    n[2].insert(1);
    arraySet(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me explain how to iterator through this set inside array. I believe an easy way is to convert it to set inside vector.

Comment: right now, you're only iterating through the first set in the array

Answer (score 1):

Size of the array needs to be passed as well to the function for you to be able to iterate through all the `sets` of the array. With just passing the pointer, size cannot be determined and dereferencing `n->begin` will iterate through only the first set.

```
void arraySet(unordered_set<int> n[], int size) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (auto it1 = n[i].begin(); it1 != n[i].end(); it1++) {
            cout << "n[" << *it1 << "]: ";
            // for(auto it = it1->begin(); it!= it1->end(); it++){
            //     cout << *it <<" ";
            // }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    unordered_set<int> n[3];
    n[0].insert(734);
    n[0].insert(23);
    n[0].insert(634);
    n[1].insert(2);
    n[1].insert(1);
    n[2].insert(1);
    arraySet(n,3);

    return 0;
}
```

Or you could use `std::vector` to contain the sets and pass it instead.

```
std::vector<unordered_set<int>> n(3); // Sets the size to 3 elements
```

The function definition would be changed to

```
void arraySet(std::vector<unordered_set<int>>& n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n.size(); i++) {
        for (auto it1 = n[i].begin(); it1 != n[i].end(); it1++) {
            cout << "n[" << *it1 << "]: ";
            // for(auto it = it1->begin(); it!= it1->end(); it++){
            //     cout << *it <<" ";
            // }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```